# TypeError: 'UndefinedType' object is not callable

Tags: altair

I'm getting a `TypeError: 'UndefinedType' object is not callable` when running the following Altair code.

```py
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data
cars = data.cars()

alt.Chart(cars).mark_point().encode(
    x=alt.X('Horsepower').axis(tickMinStep=50),
    y=alt.Y('Miles_per_Gallon').title('Miles per Gallon'),
    color='Origin',
    shape='Origin'
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vega-Altair introduced in version 5 a *method-based syntax* for setting encoding channel options (see [docs](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/encodings/index.html#method-based-syntax)).

The following line from the OP specification is using a *method-based syntax*:

```py
x=alt.X('Horsepower').axis(tickMinStep=50)
```

Where this is written as such using an *argument-based syntax*:

```py
x=alt.X('Horsepower', axis=alt.Axis(tickMinStep=50))
```

If you are facing this error you are likely on Vega-Altair version 4.x.
You have two options:

- Rewrite the *method-based syntax* to *argument-based syntax*.
- Upgrade to a recent version of Vega-Altair.

For the first, use the documentation of [Vega-Altair version 4](https://altair-viz.github.io/altair-viz-v4/).

For the latter, currently Vega-Altair version 5 can be installed using the following command:

```
pip install altair>=5
```